# VS 2015 VC++ Static Library Include Path Broken

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a bit of a problem combining a static library into another static library in my VC++ VS 2015 solution.  I'm able to get the library itself to build and go through the Librarian just fine, but when I try adding the include path I am unable to use `#include <MyFile.hpp>`, it simply fails with a 'File not found' error.

I have confirmed the include path is valid and tried it in the following different formats:

```
$(SolutionDir)lib\include
..\lib\include
\\?\$(SolutionDir)lib\include (not sure if this still helps with anything)
```

I've also tried adding these include paths to the `Include Directories` values inside the project's `VC++ Directories` properties, as well as the `Additional Include Directories` values inside the project's `C/C++` properties.  Furthermore, the library has been added as a project reference.

What's interesting to me is that I am including a DLL in exactly the same fashion, and I do not have this problem with that specific library.  The only difference between the two is that one is a DLL and the other a LIB, and obviously there is a different path between the two (though they are both in the same `$(SolutionDir)lib` base path).

I have worked around the issue by changing my include directive to be `#include "../../lib/include/MyFile.hpp"`, which has caused the build to work perfectly fine with no other changes.  Still, I'm pretty stumped as to why this LIB wouldn't behave the same way as the DLL project for the include directories.

Comment: Nothing to do with a LIB or a DLL, the compiler simply can't find a file.  If `..\..\lib\myfile.hpp` works then of course $(SolutionDir)lib\include cannot possibly work, myfile.hpp is stored in a subdirectory named lib, not include.  Using $(SolutionDir)lib should be the next guess.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.  The path is actually the same.